# How to get weighted average where latest value is weighted twice as all previous?

Tags: c, algorithm, weighted-average

I've used this before, but just can't remember it, and can't find it anywhere.

It's a running average where the newest value has twice the weight of all the previous values (combined), so that as time passes the oldest values have less and less effect. And I don't have enough memory to store the older values.

TO GET AVERAGE:

```
int sum=0;
int n = 0;
float aver = 0;
for(;;){
  float new_value = some_function();
  sum += new_value;
  ++n;
  aver = sum / n;  
}
```

But how to I get an average where the new_value is weighted to be twice the weighting of the previous average?

```
float aver = 0;
for(;;){
  float new_value = some_function();
  aver = aver * ??? + new_value * ???;

}
```

Comment: `aver = (aver + 2 * new_value) / 3;`

Comment: By "twice the weight of all the previous values" do you mean twice as much as the *combined* weights of all the others or twice as much as the *last* value?

Comment: Twice as much as last value.

Comment: A "running average" would use a filter like in the first comment, or would use a ring buffer and sum its values, in which case you sum the most recent value twice and divide by `(n + 1)`. Of course, you would not increase `n` beyond the ring buffer size.

Comment: Can you show the result you expect for some sample data?  Suppose the incoming values were these 10: `1.11
8.63
4.31
5.54
7.79
8.35
3.79
6.40
3.15
6.29` — what would you expect to be calculated (printed)?

Comment: From the question, the latest value is obviously important to you. Unless the algorithm "forgets" earlier values, new values will affect the running average less and less, even if you double them. There many ways of filtering an input value: the type in the first comment is quick to react to "spikes" and slow to recover.

Comment: Sorry.  I made a mistake.  I need "twice as much as the combined weights".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a running average where the newest value has twice the weight of all the previous values, ...
>
> how to I get an average where the `new_value` is weighted to be twice the weighting of the previous average?

Compute the special average on the sum and the latest.

```
int sum = 0;
int n = 0;
float average_special = 0.0;
for(;;) {
  float new_value = some_function();
  sum += new_value;
  ++n;
  average_special = (sum + new_value) / (n+1);  
}
```

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Doubtful overflow is an issue given that OP wants an answer based on _all previous_ which implies that a summation of all samples is not a range issue.  If anything, more likely to incur a precision issue.  True that a running average is more like `average = (1-tau)*average + tau*sample`  [Low-pass_filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Discrete-time_realization), yet OP did not ask about that

Comment: But, to me it looks like over time the new_value will have less and less affect on average_special.  I need newest value to have TWICE the affect on the average as all previous values.

Comment: EugeneSh:  That looks familier.  So in: average = (1-tau)*average + tau*sample   then tau is a weighting factor? tau=0.5: sample same weight as average.   tau=2/3: then sample has twice weight of average?  Sweet!

Comment: @DougNull There is ambiguity in "newest value to have TWICE the affect on the average as all previous values".  The "average as all previous values" is `sum/n` prior to `sum += new_value;`, no getting around that.  It appears you want 2 things, some output that has "TWICE the affect _of_ the average.  `output = (2*new_value + sum/n)/3` and a running `sum` to later calculate the average.

Comment: @DougNull But in the larger sense, what you are _asking_ for is likely not what is _needed_.  The `output = (1-tau)*output + tau*sample` is very standard code (perhaps with some adjustment for integer math) and appears to be what you _need_.